# How to add a new dictionary on my JSON list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

So I have a basic `user.json` file.

My question is: How can I add another dictionary to my JSON list?

So there is my code below, as you can see I tried this: `append`, `update`, `insert`, and I can't find any working result. The goal is to be able to add a new:

NAME: name1 // COUNTRY: coutry1 // GENDER: gender1... to the person JSON list....Thank you.
**Python code**

```py
import json

with open("user.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


new_dict = {"name": "name1",
            "Country": "Country2",
            "Gender": "Gender3"}


for person in data["person"]:
    person.update(new_dict)

with open("user.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

**user.json**

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "Country": "Montreal",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "Country": "Laval",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "name": "Annie",
      "Country": "Quebec",
      "Gender": "Female"
    },
    {
      "name": "Denise",
      "Country": "Levis",
      "Gender": "Female"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add another person object to the person list, all you have to go is to append the new object to the array of objects. You don't need to iterate over the person objects. Please check if my code below helps you:

```
with open("user.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


new_dict = {"name": "name1",
             "Country": "Country2",
             "Gender": "Gender3"}

data["person"].append(new_dict)

with open("user.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

In the python code at `person.update(new_dict)`, you are changing already existing entry `person` that will not add a new entry.